# Signing a file/binary to a specific machine using OpenSSL

Tags: security, binding, openssl

As mentioned in the question title I have a binary file which I want to
Sign for a particular Machine(Host PC). Is it possible to do, using any of the options in the OpenSSL command.
I have checked few but that doesn't seem like serving my purpose.
I would like to bind that application binary to run on only one PC using OpenSSL sign and verify concept.

Can I use to Serial_Number or -subj option

Please clarify

Comment: 1. What do you want to bind it to? A specific piece of hardware on the host PC, the hard drive itself or something else? 2. Do you compile the binary yourself?

Comment: May be like binding the signed file to the Hard drive and MAC ID combined. Yes I will compile by myself.

Answer (score 0):

The following is one of the ways to do this:

1. Add up the two IDs together and compute the hash of the result (say SHA256)
2. Sign the hash value with OpenSSL (or whatever) and store the signature in a file
3. Embed the public key from step 2 in your binary
4. When the binary loads, require the signature file to be on the system and load it, then retrieve the drive ID and MAC ID and recompute the hash, and then verify the loaded signature with the embedded public key.